# PhoneGap Email Attach after writing the file

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, email-attachments

I am using Phone Gap Application. In this,i am creating a file and writing to that file.

For this, I am using the following Code.

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        // create the file if it doesn't exist
        fileSystem.root.getFile('myFile.txt', {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(file) {
            // create writer
            file.createWriter(function(writer) {
                // write
                writer.write("Hellooo");

               }, fileSystemError);
        }, fileSystemError);
    }, fileSystemError);
```

I am composing a email with Attachment of this text file. For this, i am using the following code.

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({
        subject:     'Cordova Icon',
        attachments: ['file:///data/data/com.example.mail/myFile.txt']
    });
```

But i am unable to attach file. But the static files are attached with this code, those file are placed manually by using DDMS File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates the file in root but try to read from data/data/com.example.mail/. This should work:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
  //Get the correct directory
  fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data/data/com.example.mail/", {}, function (dir) {
    //create the file if it doesn't exist
    dir.getFile('myFile.txt', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (file) {
      // create writer
      file.createWriter(function (writer) {
        // write
        writer.write("Hellooo");    
      }, fileSystemError);
    }, fileSystemError);
  }, fileSystemError);
}, fileSystemError);
```

I written the directory as a string here, but it's better to use `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` which you can read about [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).

In general I find it very useful to actually browse the filesystem when dealing with this stuff. If you want to be able to do so in your phone without rooting you can save to Android/data/com.example.mail (`cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory`) instead.